# System to control user accounts/emails/etc

Tags: gratis, digital-asset-management, asset-management

I work for a small company that has approximately 25 direct employees plus 200+ salesman/woman that sell our products all around the country.

Each one of these will have a personal email, an username to our intranet system, might have a firewall user, VPN user, plus some third-party service accounts (IT for example will have access to AWS for example).

I've tried a few ITAM (asset management) software but they are too focused on hardware assets, with tags i.e. I can't find an adequate software.

We need like a system to manage all these kind of assets (and others that we might identify in the future), preferrably open source and PHP. We need to know everything we must cancel if one of these employees get fired, for example.

Comment: Just to complement, we thought of LDAP to centrally manage this, but it would be more complicated to adapt the systems to use it (plus, we use third-party email services that isn't compatible with LDAP).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one https://www.baxenergy.com/asset-management-platform/
This is a web based plattform which can be modified by user or admin inside the webplattform according to your needs.

However you might have to invest a lot of time to set up the system to your needs. Before your users can use it as you want to. It has only been release but it seems promising.
You can make the webside online available or only in your intranet.

The plattform is not open source, but you can manage user rights and deny employees the rights to delete what they have entered. However it is a very general tool where you can create assets, properties, tickets and forms as you desire.

Comment: I worked for years with a in-house system for such things. The most important thing I learned from it is that the actual resource assignments matter far less than the reason for them. For every account and resource, one needs to know "*Why can't I delete this?*". If you don't know why, old accounts will accumulate for fear of deleting the wrong thing. And remember, someone's account might have multiple reasons for existing, so if a manager says "*You can delete Joe's account now.*", don't believe it; Joe might still be doing work for someone in a different department.